# Paginating sitemaps

Tags: seo, sitemap

My sitemap is huge (200k+ articles), so I want to implement pagination of the sitemap itself.

My question is what parameter do most search engines look for in a sitemap pagination? `page=...` or maybe `p=...`?

I know about the sitemap index, but it would be a bit of an overhead to create that just now.

Comment: Search engines *don't* look for a pagination parameter for sitemaps; they're not "pages" in the first place. Is there a reason your question seems to be based on an assumption of this?

Comment: I'm assuming this, because I saw it in some place (can't remember exactly where), but it had something like `/sitemap.xml.1` or `/sitemap.1.xml`, but I can't remember exactly the format.

Comment: `sitemap.1.xml` can only be name of the file.

Comment: Yes, but I will also have `sitemap.2.xml` and so on, until 100. My question was: does Google know to look for `sitemap.2.xml` without me specifying a sitemap index file?

Comment: No. You can define sitemap index file as a parent for all other sitemaps. Look at [this](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemapIndexXMLExample) for definition example.

Comment: What @Zistoloen said. There is no format. The engines/index don't care what you name the individual chunks, as long as they're listed in the index file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use various sitemaps to divide yours.

In [this article](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html), it mentions:

> If you do provide multiple Sitemaps, you should then list each Sitemap
>   file in a Sitemap index file. Sitemap index files may not list more
>   than 50,000 Sitemaps and must be no larger than 10MB (10,485,760
>   bytes) and can be compressed. You can have more than one Sitemap index
>   file. The XML format of a Sitemap index file is very similar to the
>   XML format of a Sitemap file.

You can also submit various sitemaps to Google.

Comment: Yes, I know about sitemap index files, but since I am building my sitemaps on the fly, I don't know exactly at any point in time, how many exact sitemaps I will have. Hence my question, if search engines look for a variable parameter in the sitemap's name.

Comment: No. Search engine reads your sitemap index file as first (sitemap.xml you upload on Google Webmaster Tools for example). But this file defines all other sitemaps with file names you want.